# How to get control of each cell of a table Layoutpanel present in a usercontrol and that user control is used in another winform?

Tags: c#, winforms, user-controls, tablelayoutpanel

I created a User Control having a table Layout panel.Now ,that UserControl is used in another Winform Application.I want to dock a button(any Control) to each cell of tabelLayout Panel present in the usercontrol.How can I get control over each of cell of table Layout panel of that usercontrol?

Answer (score 0):

Your user control should have a method accessible that will do what you want for each cell. Just add a method like this to your UserControl.

```
    public void AddControl(Control ctrl, int rownum, int colnum)
    {
        tableLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(ctrl);
        tableLayoutPanel1.SetRow(ctrl, rownum);
        tableLayoutPanel1.SetColumn(ctrl, colnum);
        ctrl.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
    }
```

That will position the control in the cell you specify, and Dock.Fill it there.